# How to resolve error "Unable to connect to rdp server" with Remmina?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, remote-desktop, rdp

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and I am trying to connect to a `Windows 10 Home` computer remotely on the network using `Remmina`. Remote connections seem to be enabled on the Windows 10 machine (at least for a user xxx@outlook.com).
However, no matter if I try to connect (within the local network 192.168.1.20) as `admin` or the user with `xxx@outlook.com` I always get the error

```
Unable to connect to rdp server 192.168.1.20
```

after 1-2 minutes after I tried to connect. I also tried to use various Security protocols (TLS, RDP), and I checked the directory `~/.freerdp/`, which is empty.

Searching the internet for some help I only found the above tips I already tried. Is there something else I can try to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft's official web under **[Compare Windows 10 Editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare)**, Your **HOME** edition doesn't have RDP (remote desktop) facility. I'm not sure whether you have mixed up **Remote Assistance** with RDP as they are two different features.

Hope this clear your query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if there are other ways of a remote connections possible?

Comment: Given that, its a home edition, you might require an upgrade to **PRO** to use the feature. Else, all I could think of is using an app similar to Teamviewer as a remote access but not RDP.